# sg_format Low Level Format Interrupted - Kernel Errors

Tags: linux, dmesg, scsi, sasl

I was going through a sg_format low-level format from 520-byte to 4096 native byte sectors - during the process, the system lost power and the server went down hard. Now in the the kernel, I'm getting the following errors and now I can't get a /dev device to try to re-try the low-level format again.

Any help?

```
Aug 28 14:15:48 nas kernel: hpsa 0000:03:00.0: Acknowledging event: 0x80000002 (HP SSD Smart Path configuration change)
Aug 28 14:15:48 nas kernel: hpsa 0000:03:00.0: scsi 0:0:6:0: added Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  P043S1T9 EMC1920 PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathC                                 ap- En- Exp=1
Aug 28 14:15:48 nas kernel: hpsa can't handle SMP requests
Aug 28 14:15:48 nas kernel: scsi 0:0:6:0: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  P043S1T9 EMC1920 ESFA PQ: 0 ANSI: 7
Aug 28 14:15:48 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] 468975616 4096-byte logical blocks: (1.92 TB/1.75 TiB)
Aug 28 14:15:48 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 0
Aug 28 14:15:48 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
Aug 28 14:15:48 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
Aug 28 14:15:48 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
Aug 28 14:15:49 nas kernel: hpsa 0000:03:00.0: CDB 28001bf3fff000000100000000000000 : protocol error
Aug 28 14:15:49 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] tag#775 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Aug 28 14:15:49 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] tag#775 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1b f3 ff f0 00 00 01 00
Aug 28 14:15:49 nas kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 3751804800 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio cla                                 ss 0
Aug 28 14:15:49 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] tag#304 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Aug 28 14:15:49 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] tag#304 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Aug 28 14:15:49 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] tag#304 Add. Sense: Logical unit not supported
Aug 28 14:15:49 nas kernel: sd 0:0:6:0: [sde] tag#304 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1b f3 ff f0 00 00 01 00
```

Answer (score 1):

While you don't have a *disk* device (due to the disk not being in a state where it could handle block storage requests), your dmesg says that you still have the SCSI "generic" device `/dev/sg8` which will accept any SCSI command.

(It's actually the same `sg` as in "sg_format", which comes from the "SCSI Generic Utilities" and originally worked *only* with the /dev/sg devices.)